# How do I use WebStorm for Google apps script Templated HTML?

Tags: google-apps-script, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, scriptlet

Is there a way to get right understanding (and code highlight) for Google Apps Script Templated HTML (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets) in Webstorm?

Now I have it like at screenshot, so IDE doesn't understand, that in  goes javascript code

[image]

UPD: Added [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167116#focus=streamItem-27-3229863-0-0) to bugtracker of jetbrains

Comment: Why aren't you using `<script>` tags? Regardless, You shouldn't be using full-on js inside a template. See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)

Comment: 1) even using <script> I should use in that script <? ?> to get access to data variable, passed to template, so that isn't a solution

2) I can't see in Best Practices that "I shouldn't be using full-on js inside a template". only "Load data asynchronously, not in templates", "Load resources using HTTPS", "Use the HTML5 document type declaration", "Load JavaScript last" and "Take advantage of jQuery"

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?